# Как правильно: "из леса" или , "из лесу́ " или "и́з лесу"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, орфоэпия, словосочетания, окончания, словоизменение

С одной стороны, логично говорить "из леса". С другой стороны в своём стихотворении Николай Некрасов пишет:

```
Однажды, в студеную зимнюю пору,
Я из лесу вышел; был сильный мороз.
```

Ну и иногда язык всё-таки поворачивается сказать "и́з лесу" или "из лесу́".

Как всё-таки правильно?

Comment: Воспользуйтесь, пожалуйста, расстановкой ударений (скопируйте): и́з лесу, из ле́са, из лесу́ (так ведь удобнее и понятнее, правда?).

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова исправил

Comment: Так ведь у Некрасова и есть ударение на **и́з** (на предлог): *Одна́жды в студе́ную зи́мнюю по́ру // Я и́з лесу вы́шел; был си́льный моро́з.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1.** М. В. Зарва ([Русское словесное ударение](https://kak-pishetsya.net/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/Zarva-M.V.-Russkoe-slovesnoe-udarenie-2001.pdf), стр. 237):

> **лес**, леса; купить ле́су; дойти до ле́са; выйти из ле́са (и́з лесу); ходить по ле́су (по́ лесу); знать толк в ле́се; за ле́с; за ле́сом; *мн.* леса́, -о́в.

**2.** А. А. Зализняк ([Грамматический словарь русского языка: Словоизменение](https://udarenieru.ru/index.php?doc=%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%81)):

> **1)** лес: м 1c①, П₂(в) (растущий) ✧ и́з лесу//из ле́су//из ле́са; по́ лесу//по ле́су — существительное, мужской род, неодушевлённое, 2-е склонение.
>
> Особенность склонения слова «лес» в том, что в предложном падеже после предлога «в» к основе слова добавляется не окончание предложного падежа «е», а окончание дательного — «у» (в лесу́).
> Эту особую форму склонения в русской грамматике называют вторым предложным падежом...

Форма *из лесу́* является неверной.

Comment: То есть либо из леса, либо и́з лесу?

Comment: Зализняк дает все-таки три формы: **и́з лесу, из ле́су, из ле́са**. *Из лесу́* — никогда не слышала, чтобы так говорили.